# Below code is not working as i expected it to work, Instead it is reversing the input

Tags: python

This is a program, which should print a string in its descending length size. But this code is printing the given string in reverse. Any ideas about What I am missing in this code?

```
def listsorter(lst):
    lst=lst.split(" ")

    lstsize=list("a"*len(lst))
    lstindex=lstsize
    looper=len(lst)
    other=lst

    for i in range(looper):
        lstsize[i]=len(lst[i])
        lstindex[i]=lst.index(lst[i])

    while len(lstsize)>1:
        temp=max(lstsize)
        temp1=lstsize.index(temp)
        print(other[temp1])
        lstsize.pop(temp1)
    else:
        print(lst[0])

user_input=input("Enter anything\n")
listsorter(user_input)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, desired output, and fix the indentation.

Comment: Oh man. You should learn to write clean Code. Try to name the variables readable and provide comments.

Comment: `lst` doesn't look like a list, but a string of "words"?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

```
def length_sorter(s):
    words = s.split(' ')
    for w in sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True):
        print(w)

lenth_sorter('hello world i am a computer')
# prints:
computer
hello
world
am
I
a
```

To do this without using the built-in `sorted` function, you can build your own sorting algorithm.  Bubble sort is the easiest to understand.

```
def bubble_sort(a):
    a = list(a) # make sure we are using mutable objects
    keep_sorting = True
    while keep_sorting:
        keep_sorting = False
        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            if len(a[i]) < len(a[i+1]):
                a[i+1], a[i] = a[i], a[i+1]
                keep_sorting = True
    return a

def word_sorter(s):
    words = s.split(' ')
    for w in bubble_sort(words):
        print(w)

word_sorter('hello world i am a computer')
# prints:
computer
hello
world
am
I
a
```

Comment: sir, i want to do that without using sorted or sorrt method. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

edit: I guess what James wrote is what you want then?

Comment: sorry sir, i don't get you. Can you please give a little example. Will be big help :)

Comment: Sir i want,
If i input = hey hi what dones.    Output=dones what hey hi